Имитация телефона в webview python
Мне нужно сэмулировать телефон в webview python
import webview

webview.create_window("Example app", 'example.com', width=430, height=932)
webview.start()

Сайт подгружается в ПК версии, хотя размеры холста взяты с реального телефона.

Ну для начала нужно выяснить, по каким критериям сайт определяет телефон, а уже потом искать, как эти критерии имитировать через webview
